# How do I cancel a download with AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

My app downloads information using a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` and GET. The user may opt out of the download and I am trying to figure out how to cancel the download.

I came across this code:

```
- (void) cancel {
    [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

But that didn't seem to work, since the download completed.

I then tried:

```
- (void) cancel {
    for (NSURLSessionTask *task in self.tasks) {
        [task cancel];
    }
}
```

This did seem to interrupt the download, but I am not sure if this is the proper way to do this. The docs are not very helpful for this (or I haven't found it yet).

So, is the above the correct way to cancel my download? Do I need to do more cleanup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly do not want to use `cancelAllOperations`. That is fine with operation-based `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` requests, but not the task-based `AFHTTPSessionManager` requests. Sadly, `AFHTTPSessionManager` does not use operations. I understand why (wrapping the tasks in operations is surprisingly complicated given the fact that `NSURLSessionTask` delegates are specified at the session level (!), it's incompatible with background sessions, etc.), but it's too bad, as it significantly diminishes the value of `AFHTTPSessionManager`, IMHO. Mattt once said that he was [going to remedy this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1504#issuecomment-33736042), but it's never been released.

Your second approach of canceling the individual tasks is fine. You could also call `invalidateSessionCancelingTasks`, but you'd presumably have to re-instantiate the session (or the entire `AFHTTPSessionManager`) when you want to initiate more requests.